# Many to Many with 3 ids from 3 different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have 3 Models:

- Teachers
- Expertises
- Rooms

1 teacher can have many expertises;

1 teacher can have many rooms;

1 room can have many teachers;

1 expertise can have many teachers;

There is no need for a relation between Expertise and Room.

My link table, which would be the fourth model, where I store the many-to-many has 3 columns:

- teacher_id
- expertise_id
- room_id

Once the Teacher is logged in he needs to select different rooms for his expertises, so he clicks in one of his expertises listed and then there are check boxes in a new page with the rooms he can choose.

The problem is that when I save the teachers, I get a record created in the Link table, but I lose the all the expertises the teacher has. Because I had only 1 expertise_id, the relation teacher <-> expertise had all expertises deleted and only kept the one used to assign the room.

Any tips on how to manage these models?
I tried using has_many through, but obviously made some big mistakes that I can't find.

Answer (score 1):

A has and belongs to many relationship is only between two models. So in your case, what I understand is that you have to do two tables for the two has and belongs to many relationships:

- Between the teacher and the expertises (teacher_id , expertise_id)
- Between the Teacher and the rooms (teacher_id, room_id)

If there is no relationships between the Room and the Expertise, they should not be found in the same table!

Comment: Thanks Mariekou, but I think I was mistaken in my question. There is in fact a relationship between Room and Expertise too. I need the many to many column to have the three ids.
Or how should I simply add the expertise_id to my rooms_teachers link table, without declaring any relationship for the expertise_id?

Comment: I think I get it. There should not be a relationship between the teacher and the room but between the expertises and the rooms. The teacher logs in, and when he chooses an expertise he can see different available rooms for this expertise. Then you need a new model Course for example with the three ids of the teacher the expertise and the room. So:
- Teacher has and belongs to many expertises
- Expertise has and belongs to many rooms
- Course belongs_to Teacher, Expertise and Room. _ Does it help?